# ProgrammingError at / relation "home_sitesetting" does not exist LINE 1: ...ation", "home_sitesetting"."news_pagination" FROM "home_site

Tags: python, django, postgresql

My project correctly runs on localhost. But when I try to run it on the server, I get an error. On the server command line, I also get this error when executing the Migrate command:

> django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "home_sitesetting" does not
> exist LINE 1: ...ation", "home_sitesetting"."news_pagination" FROM
> "home_site...

my model:

```
from distutils.command.upload import upload
from tabnanny import verbose
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator
from ckeditor_uploader.fields import RichTextUploadingField

# Create your models here.
class SingletonBaseModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.pk = 1
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

    @classmethod
    def load(cls):
        obj, created = cls.objects.get_or_create(pk=1)
        return obj

class SiteSetting(SingletonBaseModel):
    site_title = models.CharField(max_length=250, verbose_name="عنوان سایت")
    about_us = RichTextUploadingField(verbose_name="متن درباره ما", blank =True, null= True)
    about_us_img = models.ImageField(upload_to='site/setting', verbose_name='تصویر صفحه درباره ما')
    contact_us = RichTextUploadingField(verbose_name="متن صفحه ارتباط با ما", blank =True, null= True)
    contact_us_img = models.ImageField(upload_to='site/setting',null= True, verbose_name='تصویر صفحه ارتباط با ما')
    phone = models.CharField(null=True, blank=False, max_length=12)
    address = models.TextField(verbose_name="آدرس", null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='ایمیل', max_length=100)
    instagram = models.URLField(max_length=200, verbose_name='آدرس اینستاگرام', null=True)
    telegram = models.URLField(max_length=200, verbose_name='آدرس کانال تلگرام', null=True)
    fb = models.URLField(max_length=200, verbose_name='آدرس فیس بوک', null=True)
    twitter = models.URLField(max_length=200, verbose_name='آدرس توییتر', null=True)
    youtube = models.URLField(max_length=200, verbose_name='آدرس یوتیوب', null=True)
    linkedin = models.URLField(max_length=200, verbose_name='آدرس لینکدین', null=True)
    whtasapp = models.URLField(max_length=200, verbose_name='آدرس واتس اپ', null=True)
    dark_logo_img = models.ImageField(upload_to='site/logo', verbose_name='لوگوی سایت (نسخه دارک)')
    light_logo_img = models.ImageField(upload_to='site/logo', verbose_name='لوگوی سایت (نسخه لایت)')
    fav_icon = models.ImageField(upload_to='site/favicon', verbose_name = 'favicon')
    article_pagination = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(25)], default=10, verbose_name='تعداد مقالات در هر صفحه')
    news_pagination = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(25)], default=10, verbose_name='تعداد اخبار در هر صفحه')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'تنظیم'
        verbose_name_plural = 'تنظیمات'
    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.site_title


class ContactForm(models.Model):
    message_username = models.CharField(max_length=60,null= True,default='user', verbose_name=" نام کاربر")
    message_title = models.CharField(max_length=60, verbose_name="عنوان پیام")
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='ایمیل', max_length=100)
    message_body = models.TextField(verbose_name="متن پیام")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'پیام کاربر'
        verbose_name_plural = 'پیام های کاربران'
    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.message_title
```

Comment: Did you add your database connection and run your migrations?

Comment: Yes, I did. But on the server to execute the command "python manage.py migrate" I encounter the error I mentioned above.